# Is there a way to code in VBA that would automate writing text in columns for duplicate values?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first question here so apologies in advance for any mistakes or oversights.

I am working with a spreadsheet that contains ~30,000 rows of people's details. 
There are duplicate entries for each person (same surname, DOB etc.), but the first names are frequently different. For example, John Smith, J Smith, J M Smith.

[Spreadsheet Extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeKDd.png)

I wish to write code that would look through the surnames and DOB iteratively to find a matching group. Then since the longest first name is always the correct entry, the greatest first name length out of the group would be the one I want to state as correct.

For example, in my attached image:

Cells C2, C3 and C4 all have surname 'Solo'. If the code went for the next cell down (C5) it would be 'Stark' so it would stop counting there.

It would then confirm that all these 'Solo' are the same person by checking all the respective DOBs match (D2:D4). After that, it would calculate which cell (B2, B3 or B4) has the largest length. In this case, B2 has the longest length.

Finally, it would write in the 'Comment' cell for the whole group that all these match row 2 which has a corresponding 'ID' of '1' - 'Correct to ID 1'.

Thank you for your assistance. I hope this is somewhat clear!

Comment: *This is my first question here so apologies in advance for any mistakes or oversights.* - Welcome! We want to help, but we don't write code from scratch. Update your question with code you have tried and what is not working and we will surely jump in.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. I haven't used VBA in many years so I am very rusty. I will try to put something together then get back to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) with Surname & DOB as the key and the row number of the longest first name as the value.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ProcessNames()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim dict As Object, sKey As String
    Dim iLastRow As Long, iRow As Long

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Names") ' change to suit
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For iRow = 2 To iLastRow
        ' create key using LastName and DOB
        sKey = UCase(ws.Cells(iRow, "C")) & Format(Cells(iRow, "D"), "YYYYMMDD")

        If dict.exists(sKey) Then
            ' compare length of first names, store longest
            If Len(ws.Cells(iRow, "B")) > Len(ws.Cells(dict(sKey), "B")) Then
               dict(sKey) = iRow
            End If
        Else
            dict(sKey) = iRow
        End If

    Next

    ' update correct IDs in Comment
    For iRow = 2 To iLastRow
        sKey = UCase(ws.Cells(iRow, "C")) & Format(Cells(iRow, "D"), "YYYYMMDD")
        ws.Cells(iRow, "E") = "Correct to ID " & ws.Cells(dict(sKey), "A")
    Next

    MsgBox dict.Count & " names found in rows 2 to " & iLastRow, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @CDP1802, much appreciated!